# Which printers can I use when running Ubuntu from USB stick?

Tags: drivers, usb, printing

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 from a USB stick, and need to print simple text pages over USB without installing any drivers (or at least, without connecting to the internet, but I'd like to keep it simple). I'm no Ubuntu expert, but in any case I don't seem to find a list of standard printer drivers that are guaranteed to work?

I can borrow or buy a printer, anything will do as long as it's cheap and easily available in Belgium.

Is there any way to know which printers this should work with? Something along the lines of 'Any HP Deskjet will do' is fine. Or a definitive list.

Comment: You can find a list of CUPS supported printers at https://www.cups.org/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, printer compatibility can be something of a try-and-see affair. In my experience:

- HP printer tend to work out of the box
- Brother printers have available drivers that work well, but must be installed
- Canon provides drivers that work, but often their printers work without
  needing to use the manufacturer install tools

There is a very complete rundown here: https://haydenjames.io/finding-linux-compatible-printers/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//askubuntu.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Added context from what appears in the link and also conforms to my experience.

Comment: That's a much better answer now. +1